# UI GRID - Custom Cell Templates Code Separation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to customize the cells using cellTemplates in UI-GRID. For this, I am defining templates in .js file, like this :

```
var template1 = '<div class="div1">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>';

var template2 = '<div class="div2">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>';

var template3 = '<div class="div3">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>';
```

I want to separate the HTML codes from .js file. Is there a way to define these templates separately in some .html file and using them in .js file. ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cellTemplate` differents ways:

```
var columnDefs = [
  { field: 'name', cellTemplate: 'name-template.html' },
  { field: 'name', cellTemplate: 'myTemplateId' },
  { field: 'name', cellTemplate: $.get('url-to-your-template.html') }
];
```

Your template can contain:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a href="mailto:{{ COL_FIELD }}">Send E-Mail</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by coding  as mentioned below

```
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "myTemplate.html">
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a href="mailto:{{ COL_FIELD }}">Send E-Mail</a></div>
</script>
```

and then in your column definition provide the id mentioned for script tag in cellTemplate

```
var columnDefs = [
{ field: 'name', cellTemplate: 'myTemplate.html' }  
];
```

Comment: this is more feasible, especially if you dont need to use (or dont want to use) `$()` libraries. IMHO